# Using normal square bottom bracket on crankset designed for E type?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I am building a LHT 26" and I am planning to use a square taper bottom bracket. Also want to have triple chainring with a small chainring 22T so bought the Shimano Alivio FC-M430, about the best crankset Shimano lets me buy these days for square taper and these settings. But I have realized this crankset is supposed to be used with an E type BB. I really don´t want to use this type of FD so my question is: Can I still buy a ´normal´non E type of BB (say UN55 113mm) for this crankset? Will the chainline be badly affected? Will I have to add spacers?
Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: The (-E) is optional.  Just need to make sure you get the correct length BB to get the chain line correct.

Comment: In my mind, e-type front derailleurs are the ones that don't mount to the frame at the seat tube.  Instead they have a large integrated hole that slips between the right-hand BB cup and the BB housing.  Many have some kind of prop that leans on the frame but its not clamped on.  This is nothing to do with an ebike at all.   A BB cartridge is completely standard, and there are no e-type BB cartridges.

Answer (score 1):

Cranks are never e-type specific. Some frames dictate you use an e-type FD and BB. You're free to use whatever normal square taper BB.

Comment: Thanks - I guessed that in spite of wrong information by sellers. Just have to worry about chainline and BB length now!